# Transit in Schengen airport without ticket

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, ath

I have a friend visiting Europe. She was issued a Schengen visa with one entry. She flew from Hong Kong to Athens via Singapore.

She had booked a separate flight from Athens to Barcelona via Sofia. Only after she arrived in Sofia ready to take plane to Barcelona she was told she can't enter Spain as her visa has been used up.

Will she able to take the return flight to Hong Kong from Athens?

After arriving from a non-Schengen country to Athens airport you either go through the Schengen border check or the transit zone.

The problem is she is unable to check in online. I'm wondering if they allow her to take the flight.

Normally she would get a boarding pass at the departure check-in, but for that she needs to enter Schengen.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend should be able to transit in Athens from Sofia to Hong Kong, **provided** that she is traveling on a single booking such that she doesn't need to pick up and re-check baggage. (She would need to enter the Schengen are in order to reach the baggage claim).

Traveling on a single booking, she should get boarding passes for both legs when checking in in Sofia; there's no need to visit a check-in desk at Athens.

Comment: The flight from Sofia to Athens is a separate booking from single booking Athens to Hong Kong. If she had luggage they would just unload it in Athens and she can't take it.

Comment: @user68903: Doesn't look good. If she booked the tickets through a travel agency, now would be a really good time to call them and hear if they can offer any help or advice. Otherwise, _probably_ the best option would be to call the airline for the Athens-Hong Kong flight, explain the situation, and hear if they'd be willing to change that booking or amend it with a new initial leg Sofia-Athens with an interlining airline.